# How to catch if-statement block and name block in regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, if-statement, named, balanced-groups

How to capture if-statement block. I've capture the else-statement block in a named Group.
My current solution is at this permalink: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=7663e386-fcc0-4f19-b613-e9e58374a5d7

```
@if\([^)]*\)\s*{(((?>(?<open>@if\([^)]*\)\s*{)|@{[^}]*}|[^}@]+|(?:}else{(?<else>([^}]*))(?=}endif@))|(?<-open>}endif@)))*(?(open)(?!)))}endif@
```

Content inside statement block are html related. I.e.

```
@if(prevbutton.visible=='True'){
    <div style="float:left; display:inline; margin-right: 5px; padding-top:7px;">
        <span class="arrows_prev" id="prevbottom" title="@{prevbutton.toindex}" rel="prev" data-page-number="@{prevbutton.toindex}"></span>
    </div>
}else{
    test
}endif@
```

Answer (score 0):

Took another approach for solving the problem.
Here is my solution:

```
(?<if_else>(?<=@if\([^)]*\){).*(?=}else{))|(?<if>(?<=@if\([^)]*\){).*(?=}endif@))|(?<else>(?<=}else{)[^}]*(?=}endif@))
```